# getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for MultitenantAddressingBasedDispatcher

Tags: osgi, wso2

I am getting class not found exception for one of the jars from wso2 app server 5.1.0.
I have copied here the stack trace as below:

```
[2013-09-16 14:04:17,562]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder} -  org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor
[2013-09-16 14:04:17,578] FATAL {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occured while loading the Axis configuration from C:\WSO2AS\WSO2AS~1.0\bin\../repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:190)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.createNewConfigurationContext(CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:398)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantAddressingBasedDispatcher
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.loadHandler(Utils.java:149)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processPhaseList(AxisConfigBuilder.java:549)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processPhaseOrders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:580)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:150)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.populateAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:308)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:188)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantAddressingBasedDispatcher
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.loadHandler(Utils.java:116)
        ... 47 more
```

Due to this exception described above, the UI of Application Server fails to come up.
The bundle status information is as below:

```
227     ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.caching.stub_4.1.0
228     ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.caching.ui_4.1.0
229     ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.captcha.mgt_4.1.0
230     ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.cluster.mgt.core_4.1.0
231     ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.coordination.common_4.1.0
232     ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.coordination.core_4.1.0
233     ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.core_4.1.0
234     ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator_4.1.0
235     ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.core.common_4.1.0
236     ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.core.commons.stub_4.1.0
237     ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.core.services_4.1.0
```

After little search I found out that **org.wso2.carbon.core_4.1.0** contains the class 
**org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantAddressingBasedDispatcher**.
I am still not clear about that class's visibility  to classloader even if its bundle is ACTIVE..

Any guideline on this will be very helpful..
Thanks & regards,Parimal

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with httpcore-nio version and the mentioned revision change is not there in the pack.